# Current culture - display euro symbol (€) instead of EUR string

Tags: c#, razor, currency, culture

With current culture set to "sk-SK" (Slovakia with currency - euro) I want to show euro symbol (€) instead of "EUR" string when displaying price as currency in Razor with `Price.ToString("c")`.

When I change current culture to, for example German ("de-DE"), the euro symbol (€) is displayed.

I would like to show euro symbol when displaying price with Slovak culture as well (not "EUR" string).

I think this is OS dependent (our OS is Windows Server 2012) but changing default currency suggested by this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/240216/how-to-change-windows-default-currency-from-dollars-to-euros/ (in our case from EUR to €) doesn't change the way currency symbol is displayed. How can I display the currency as € instead of EUR?

Comment: And what is the problem to [change currency symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol(v=vs.110).aspx) in `sk-SK` locale? It has setter.

Comment: What's the problem to write `€` into razor code? (for example: `@Html.Label("Something")€`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("sk-SK");
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
double Price = 10.0;
Console.WriteLine(Price.ToString("c"));
```

This produces the output

> 10,00 €

Another possibility is to pass the culture info as `IFormatProvider` in `ToString()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Price.ToString("c",ci));
```

Comment: This provides `£10.00` for me. Where did you use `ci`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid setting the currency symbol explicitly in code. This is a larger project and I don't want to make such changes, which would make it prone to future mistakes (for example if currency changed). I migrated this web site from windows server 2008 where `Price.ToString("c")` with `sk-SK` locale displayed the price with the euro symbol. If I don't find a different solution, I'll mark your response as answer. Thank you

Comment: @SeM: You are right, I forgot a line in the code. Never actually set `ci` to `CultureInfo`.

Comment: @waka or you can just add it in `ToString()` method - `... Console.WriteLine(Price.ToString("c", ci));`

Comment: But anyway, it returns `10,00 ?` for me.

Comment: @SeM: I like that one even better. The `?` is dependant on the console where you show the output. The built in console of VisualStudio for example should show `€` correctly. The Windows cmd shows `?` for me as well (change the symbol to `$` and it should show up correctly on the cmd window).